# How to locate this HTML tag through Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

HTML:

```
<img src="dash_img/dash-img_07.png">
```

HTML Image:

[image]

Here there is no attribute to get the xpath, I tried by link text but that too failed.

Comment: How did you try? Share your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To locate the element you can use either of the following solutions:

- *CssSelector*:

  ```
  div.Timesheet li.time-bg > a > img[src='dash_img/dash-img_07.png']
  ```
- *XPath*:

  ```
  //div[@class='Timesheet']//li[@class='time-bg']/a/img[@src='dash_img/dash-img_07.png']
  ```
- *XPath* (based on the text *View Timesheet*):

  ```
  //span[contains(., 'View Timesheet')]//preceding::a[1]/img
  ```

Comment: @Ponsukumarlingam I created the _xpath_ and the _cssSelector_ on the fly haven't used any tool as such.

Comment: Thanks, from your xpath i can understand how you derived this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way to find it would be to use a CSS selector

```
img[src='dash_img/dash-ig_07.png']
```

or XPath

```
//img[@src='dash_img/dash-ig_07.png']
```

CSS selectors are faster, better supported, and a simpler syntax to learn but there are times when you have to use XPath, e.g. when you want to find an element by contained text.

But... I would suggest that you find it based on the image label, "View Timesheet",

```
//span[.='View Timesheet ']/preceding::img[1]
```

Comment: Also CSS-selector has no such axis as `preceding`, `parent`, etc...  :)

Comment: @Andersson I did say that CSS selectors have a simpler syntax... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath should find it

```
WebElement temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'<img src="dash_img/dash-img_07.png">')]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
"//div[@class='list']//a/img"
```